# Creating linked list with user input returns error 0xC0000005 on CodeBlocks

Tags: c, list

When I'm debugging and going step by step everything works fine but when I run it my program crashes after taking the second input in the second iteration. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next, *prev;
};
typedef struct node *node;


int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    node head, number, temp;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->prev = NULL;
    number = head;

    printf("Enter size of list: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter elements of list: ");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number->x);
        number->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp = number;
        number = number->next;
        number->prev = temp;
    }
    number->next=NULL;

    number = head;
    printf("/nThe list is: ");
    while(number->next != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%d ", number->x);
        number=number->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong in my code?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added whole code.

Comment: Please show ALL your data variable declarations

Comment: This particular piece of code looks ok. Show us a little bit more context. Show the variables declarations.

Comment: Added my code on the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

No. This is wrong. `node` is an alias for `struct node *`; you're not allocating enough memory. You need to allocate space for a `struct node`, not for a pointer to `struct node`.

Do this instead:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Or even better:

```
head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

The same for this line:

```
number->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Replace it with:

```
number->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Or:

```
number->next = malloc(sizeof(*number->next));
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally get it now. Although I'm not quite sure I understand the second notation `head = malloc(sizeof(*head));`
Could you briefly explain how `*head` is used in this case?

Comment: @user3484582 Sure! `sizeof()` can be given a type name or an expression. In the latter case, it returns the size of the type of that expression. Also, `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand (except with variable-length arrays). So, when you do something like `sizeof(*head)`, the compiler knows that the type of `*head` is `struct node`, so `sizeof()` returns the correct size, that is, the size of `struct node`. It is generally a good practice to do this when allocating memory for pointers because it prevents the kind of mistake you did.